# How to get the loop to output the correct array sizes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

In my loop I have three different variables I need to ouput, A, the average of V and Alpha. Before i was just getting one value for each but fixed this by using the append function.

```
An=np.array([51,101,201,301,501])#No. agents
t=10#time steps
MM=3#agent memory
r=5#repetitions
A=np.array([])
V=np.array([])
Alpha=np.array([])
Vav=np.array([])
for agentcount in np.arange(0,5): #count over agents
    N=An[agentcount]

    for M in np.arange(1,MM+1):
        for crep in np.arange(1,r+1): 
             win=(np.random.rand(M,1)>0.5).astype(int) #winning record 
             s1=(np.random.rand(2**M,N)>0.5).astype(int) #random strat
             s2=(np.random.rand((2**M),N)>0.5).astype(int) #alternative 
             payout=np.zeros([2,N])#empty payout record
             for tc in np.arange(1,t+1):
                  cc=np.abs((1+ np.dot((2**(np.arange(0,M))),win)))
                  nex1=s1[cc-1,:].reshape(501)
                  nex2=s2[cc-1,:].reshape(501)
                  nexts=np.stack((nex1,nex2),axis=0)
    
                  for cn in np.arange(0,N+1): #better strat
                      if (payout[0,cn-1]>payout[1,cn-1]):
                          Next=nex1
                      else:
                          Next=nex2
                  Asum=np.sum(Next)/N
                  A=np.append(A,Asum)
                  winning=(A<0.5).astype(int)
                  winning=np.transpose(winning)
                  payout=payout+(nexts==winning)#update record
              V=np.append(V,np.var(A))
              Vav=np.append(Vav,np.mean(V))
          Alpha=np.append(Alpha,2**M/N)
```

Using the indentations I would expect A, Vav and Alpha to be  1d arrays size t, r and MM respectively. But for A i am getting size t*r*MM and Vav size r*MM. How do I get the sizes to correspond to certain sections of the loop?
Thanks

Comment: Something is off with the indentations. The lines following `for crep in np.arange(1,r+1):` should be indented 1 level... Could you fix this? Not sure which indentations where planned for the last three lines.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure what your are after. But as you initialise `A`, `Vav` and `Alpha` outside your loops and add a value during each pass, the array length is as expected. I hope simplifying your code clarifies things:

```
An=np.array([51,101,201,301,501])#No. agents
t=10#time steps
MM=3#agent memory
r=5#repetitions
A=np.array([])
V=np.array([])
Alpha=np.array([])
Vav=np.array([])
for agentcount in np.arange(0,5): #count over agents
    for M in np.arange(1,MM+1):
        for crep in np.arange(1,r+1): 
             for tc in np.arange(1,t+1):
                  A=np.append(A,'Asum')
             V=np.append(V,'np.var(A)')
             Vav=np.append(Vav,'np.mean(V)')
        Alpha=np.append(Alpha,'2**M/N')
```

E.g., a value is added to `Vav` `r`-times during each `MM`-passes of the outer loop.

To get (for example) an array `A` of length `t`, it would be required to initialise `A` right before looping over `t`. But this would mean that `A` is overwritten each time... (and that is probably not intended?)

Comment: Thankyou, I am still confused because in Matlab the code A(tc)=np.sum(Next)/N would repeat the sum tc times and give a tc sized array. How would i do this in python? A[ct]=" would give an error